# Access to assets android

Tags: android, assets

I'd like to access to access in my android class.

I know I can use getAssets but I'm working on an util class not an activity so I can't access to context.

I can add a param in my constructor or a setter but this is not very proper

Il there a good solution to access my assets in an util class ?

Thanks

Edit:

```
File file = new File("file:///");
String[] list = file.list();
for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```

but list is null

Comment: What's there in your assets folder?

Comment: It's really not working. I have tried files with different extensions

Comment: I use it like `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/no_network.html")` way to directly load html files into my webview from the assets folder. You can try creating a `File` object by removing one of the slashes from the front near the `file:///`. Not sure if that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution using context this is proper

```
public static Properties getProperties(Context context)
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        prop.load(context.getAssets().open("config.properties"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v(TAG+"_PROPERTIES","FileNotFoundException",e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(TAG+"_PROPERTIES","IOException",e);
    }

    return prop;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `file:///android_asset/assetname.extension` to refers to the asset.
Probably create a `File` with the path as above to your asset.

Comment: I don't think the way you did, it will work. You need to have android_asset/filename, This is somehow refers to stuff in your assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
File file = new File("file:///android_asset/");
String[] list = file.list();
for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
    System.out.println(list[i]);
}
```